# Azure function returning intermittent 502 errors

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function runtime version 1 that is returning 502 Bad Gateway errors after running for sometime. I am not sure what could be the reason. Logs don't provide anything useful.[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error try this workaround:

- Firtsly, go to Azure portal
- Then Click on your Azure function App
- Then click on `configuration` in settings
- Then Click on `On` in `https only` segment

[image]

These might be also caused because of less number of resources, you can increase your resources by upgrading the plan.

According [Microsft-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli,in-process,v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp) it says, you are using azure function version 1, try Upgrading function runtime to 4.

Comment: The setting is already set to ON. Also, the function app is in premium plan. For our use case, we cannot do runtime 4, only runtime 1.